# PHP redirect to another page and pass value?

Tags: php

I have a problem where I need to redirect to another page and pass a value, which is easy and I know how to do, except that theres the old header problem: **Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ... line 17**

```
<?php include('m_a2_functions.php'); ?>
<?php global_header(LOGIN); ?>
<?php login(); ?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    connect();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT password from users where username = '$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("There was an error executing the query $query:<br/>".mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $encrypted_pass = $row[0];

    if (crypt($password, $encrypted_pass) == $encrypted_pass) {
        $flag = "y";
        header('Location: m_a2_view.php?flag=y');
    }

}
?>
<?php validation(); ?>
<?php page_footer(); ?>
```

This is all fine, except that there is a problem with the header part. It won't redirect.

**GLOBAL HEADER FUNCTION IN FUNCTIONS.PHP**

```
<?php function global_header($page_title){ ?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?> <- LINE 17
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title><?php echo "MARK - " . $page_title; ?></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="logo"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

**LINE 17**

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
```

I know that's what is causing it. It loads global_header at the start of my page and then can't redirect to another page. Soon as I hit submit, my page should redirect, but it cannot!

Even if I start removing things, it won't work. It will EVENTUALLY work after getting rid of global_header() completely, something which I can't do.

Comment: Put your redirect before the call to `global_header()`

Comment: Use output buffering http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having this issue is because your script is multiple open `<?php` and closing `?>` of `PHP` tag which has `space` and `new line` between them ...

Replace

```
<?php include('m_a2_functions.php'); ?>
<?php global_header(LOGIN); ?>
<?php login(); ?>
<?php
```

With

```
<?php 
include('m_a2_functions.php');
//global_header(LOGIN);
//login();
```

Your Script

```
    include ('m_a2_functions.php');
    if (isset ( $_POST ['submit'] )) {
        connect ();
        $username = $_POST ['username'];
        $password = $_POST ['password'];

        $query = "SELECT password from users where username = '$username'";
        $result = mysql_query ( $query ) or die ( "There was an error executing the query $query:<br/>" . mysql_error () );
        $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result );
        $encrypted_pass = $row [0];

        if (crypt ( $password, $encrypted_pass ) == $encrypted_pass) {
            $flag = "y";
            header ( 'Location: m_a2_view.php?flag=y' );
        }

    } else {
        echo global_header ( "LOGIN" );
        login ();
    }

    validation ();
    page_footer ();

    function global_header($page_title) {
        $content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title><?php echo "MARK - ' . $page_title . '</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head> 
    <body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="logo"></div>';

        return $content;
    }
```

Comment: No sir, that is not the error! `global_header();` sends headers already, so I can't send them again using `header();`!

Comment: Even if you remove global header .. you would still get the same error ..... give it a try and see  .. i"ll update my answer to what i think is the most valid approach

Comment: Nope, did that before I made the post and it worked. User minitech gave a very clean and optimal solution.

Comment: Agree with Baba. Minitech's solution was the best drop in option, but the code could use a refactor.

Comment: edit: Actually your solution was better, thank you lol. I am an ignoramus.

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by there already being output before the redirection. What you can do is buffer said output if you'd really like to keep things in that order with that coding style:

```
<?php ob_start(); ?>
<?php include('m_a2_functions.php'); ?>
<?php global_header(LOGIN); ?>
<?php login(); ?>
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    connect();
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $query = "SELECT password from users where username = '$username'";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("There was an error executing the query $query:<br/>".mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $encrypted_pass = $row[0];

    if (crypt($password, $encrypted_pass) == $encrypted_pass) {
        $flag = "y";
        header('Location: m_a2_view.php?flag=y');
        ob_end_clean(); // Discard the buffer
    } else {
        ob_end_flush(); // Display the contents of the buffer
    }
}
?>
<?php validation(); ?>
<?php page_footer(); ?>
```